# How to select a subset of mnist training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, training-data, mnist

I have trouble on how to select a subset of mnist training set which contains M points to train the 1-NN classifier because the number of original training points are too large.

That is , I need to figure out a scheme that takes as input a labeled training set as well as a number M, and return a subset.of the training set of size M.

Besides, uniform-random selection is not allowed.((that is, just picking M of the training points at random)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to train your network with a a data-generator.
It loads only one batch of data step for step. You will not have issues with your data anymore. Furthermore, it is able to use multithreading.
So loading and maybe preprocessing of your data is not a bottleneck.

Here is a good example:
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still don't know how to select a subset using your method.

Comment: Can you explain the format of your data - e.g. are these image files like '.png' on your drive or some '.h5' files etc.

Comment: they are .gz files from mnist dataset.